# Can't play NightSkyHD because file-type is unknown

Tags: games

I've only been using Ubuntu for a day now, so bear with me here.

I downloaded NightSkyHD from the Humble Indie Bundle website and it's now in my downloads folder.

I open my downloads folder, click on the "nightskyhd-linux-1324519044.tar.gz" folder and see that the file type for NightSkyHD is unknown. In Windows, the file would be ".exe".

Am I missing an application or something that lets me play games? Did I download the wrong file from the HIB website? Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The file that you downloaded is not the easiest to use option, there are two better ways to download and install it:

- If you have a Ubuntu account, you can click on the big orange "Download for Ubuntu" button, you will be asked for your username and password. After a while you should be able to download and install the games from the Software Centre.

[image]

- If you want to download it the "old-way", download the deb files, not the tar.gz. Double click on then to install.

With both methods you should be able to start the game from [the dash](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html).

Comment: Thank you! When I saw all the different files to download I didn't know which one to choose.